# Prisma generates database tables with uppercase in mysql. Is there any way to generate tables only in lowercase?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04, prisma, prisma-graphql

Prisma generates database tables with uppercase in MySQL. Is there any way to generate tables only in lower case?

Answer (score 5):

At the moment you have to do that manually with [@map and @@map](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model#mapping-model-names-to-tables-or-collections).

You can read more about this [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/use-custom-model-and-field-names).

Here an example:

```
model PostInCategories {
  category Category @map(name: "category_id")
  post     Post     @map(name: "post_id")

  @@unique([post, category], name: "post_id_category_id_unique")
  @@map(name: "post_in_categories")
}
```